# What lives in the components folder?

Tags: express, yeoman, bower

### Background

I've used the [yeoman](http://yeoman.io/) tool to set up an [MVC Express.js app](https://github.com/petecoop/generator-express#mvc-apps) with a directory structure like this:

```
app
  controllers
  models
  views
config
  config.js
  express.js
public
  components      <-- This one here
  css
  img
  js
Gruntfile.js
app.js
bower.json
package.json
```

### Question

What is the implied use of the components directory? Is it like the vendor folder in Rails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's used for frontend vendor libs you install with bower

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply!

Comment: Just a quick sanity check: say I need leaflet.js, I would ```bower install leaflet``` into that location yes?

Comment: yes it should, by default bower uses the folder bower_components but it  probably has been changed in the file .bowerrc to just components